# How to output a map with a vector of pairs?

Tags: c++

I have the following map;

```
 std::map<long, std::vector<std::pair<long,long>>> G;
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to print the pair values in it, could anyone help me out?

Comment: Can someone explain the etiquette of this website?  Why does a post like this get downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a loop:

```
for (const auto & p : G)
{
    std::cout << p.first << " => {";
    for (const auto & q : p.second)
        std::cout << "(" << q.first << ", " << q.second << ")";
    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem.